# Has the existence of a 3-MOLS(10) containing a self-orthogonal Latin square and its transpose been eliminated?

Tags: co.combinatorics, latin-square

McKay, Meynert, Myrvold (2006) (*Small latin squares, quasigroups, and loops*, [DOI:10.1002/jcd.20105](https://doi.org/10.1002/jcd.20105), [author copy](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/ls_final.pdf)) computationally eliminate the possibility of set of 3 mutually orthogonal Latin squares of order 10, i.e., a 3-MOLS(10), where one of the Latin squares has a non-trivial autoparatopism group (i.e., it has some symmetry).

I'm unsure of what the current status for 3-MOLS(10) in which one is self-orthogonal (i.e., orthogonal to its transpose), and another is its transpose.  It seems like this could be within the realm of computational feasibility.

**Question**: Has the existence of a 3-MOLS(10) containing a self-orthogonal Latin square and its transpose been eliminated?

Comment: I added a link to a free copy of the paper, and the title :-)